# Django uploaded files not displaying in template page

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to display the top 5 recently posted files but doesnt seem to show up.
When i get all the objects by using Model.objects.all(), it gives me all the objects from Db but when i am trying to get the top 5, it does not display.
Kindly help and suggest me. Thanks

my views.py is

```
def about_experiment(request, ex_link_name):
  researcher = None
  study = None
  posts = None
  exp = get_object_or_404(Experiment,link_name = ex_link_name)
  high_scores = ScoreItem.objects.filter(experiment=exp,active=True)
  context = {
    'request': request,
    'exp':exp,
    'high_scores': high_scores,
    'awards':AwardItem.objects.filter(experiment=exp,visible=True),
    'posts':Help.objects.filter().order_by('-date')[0],
    'documents':Help.objects.filter().order_by('-document')[:5]
  }

  if exp.about_file:
    context['about_file'] = settings.EXPERIMENT_DIRS+exp.about_file.get_include_path()

  if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AboutHelp(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit = False)
            obj.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/about/%s/' %ex_link_name)
            #return redirect(reverse('lazer.views.about_experiment', kwargs={ 'ex_link_name':obj.link_name }))

  else:
      form = AboutHelp()

  return render(request, 'about_experiment.html', context)
```

destination template page

```
  <div class="tab-pane" id="irb">
          <h4> List of file(s) uploaded:</h4>
        <!--File upload-->
            {% if documents %}
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"> {{ documents.document }} </a></li>
                </ul>
            {% else %}
                <p>No such documents available.</p>
            {% endif %}
       <!--File upload ends-->
```

Answer (score 1):

`documents` is a queryset and you are picking top 5. You need to do this like this.

```
  <div class="tab-pane" id="irb">
      <h4> List of file(s) uploaded:</h4>
    <!--File upload-->
            {% for doc in documents %}
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"> {{ doc.document }} </a></li>
            </ul>
            {% empty %}
            <p>No such documents available.</p>
            {% endfor %}
   <!--File upload ends-->
```